# Django Admin - Filter ManyToManyField with through model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

How can I filter a queryset inside the Admin page of an object that has a `ManyToManyField` relation with a manually defined `through` model?

Given models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Main(models.Model):
    main_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    m2mfield = models.ManyToManyField(Foo, through="FooBar")

class FooBar(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Inside admin.py

```
class M2MInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Main.m2mfield.through
    extra = 1

class MainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [M2MInlineAdmin,]
   ...

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        print('called formfield_for_manytomany')
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def get_field_queryset(self, db, db_field, request):
        print('called get_field_queryset')
        return super().get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
```

I try to access both of these methods, but none of them are called if I specify a `through` table. However, they do get called if the ManyToMany relation is simply defined as like this:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    main_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    m2mfield = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

Is there a method to filter the queryset when a through table is specified (while being able to access the `request` context)?

**EDIT:**

The methods are indeed called when the ManyToManyField has a `through` model specified, only if there are no `fieldsets` specified inside the `modelAdmin` class.

How to access these methods when `fieldsets` are defined?

Comment: I am using django==2.2.3

Comment: @ChillarAnand I want to filter in create/change view.

Comment: Upgraded to 2.2.3 and tested on it. On change/create view, it is always calling formfield_for_manytomany. Not able to reproduce the mentioned scenario. https://github.com/ChillarAnand/library/blob/master/trash/admin.py Can you paste entire model admin code? Is there something else which is missing from the above snippet?

Comment: @ChillarAnand well, I investigated a bit and noticed that the methods are indeed called, but I am specifying `fieldsets` and for some reason if this variable is defined, the methods are not called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`formfield_for_manytomany` method [seems to be called](https://github.com/django/django/blob/42b9a23267f14be39b9b00958e18d5746783208e/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L155-L156) only when default form is used. When fieldsets is defined, it is using a different form which is why above method is not getting called.

Since you are using tabular admin for many to many field, you can override get_queryset to filter with field.

```
class M2MInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Main.fruits.through
    extra = 1

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(M2MInlineAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.filter(some_arg=some_value)
        return qs
```

Alternatively, you can write a custom model form and use it in admin instead of default form.

```
class MainAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Main
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # custom setup


class MainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MainAdminForm
```

Comment: Thank you, `get_queryset` inside the `TabularInline` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `formfield_for_foreignkey()` method on the inline class.

```
class M2MInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Main.m2mfield.through
    extra = 1

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I need to access the request context while doing this filtering (`object.id` and `request.user`)

Comment: I'm getting `inlineformset_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`

Comment: @drec4s did you add the init method above to the custom formset? The user line above `super()` is important. It allows you to use `self.user` in your filtering.

Comment: yes, copied exactly as you posted, I am setting `self.user` above the `super()` method inside `__init__`

Comment: Wow, I was definitely thinking too hard.. see above for a much easier solution.